# android studio is unable to resolve a number of dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

i just installed android studio with sdk and have java jdk in my pc. When i am trying to build the "hello world" empty project i am getting errors saying unresolved dependencies. 
[image]
here's the image of  errors i get when the empty project is finished building itself.

[image]
gradle-app file

Comment: Run `gradlew dependencies` in your root project to see the real error from Gradle. Maybe the `Gradle Console` tool window also shows you the error already.

Answer (score 0):

Your not showing your full `build.gradle` file but it looks like you don't have any configured `repositories`.

Add this to your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```